# What is an alternative to a cement truck that would allow more working time?

Tags: storage, cement

I'd like to know if there is an alternative to a cement truck. 
I'm planning to build a sports court which requires me to build a concrete foundation.

I asked the cement company and they said the truck can stay max. up to 2 hours at my place. That's not enough time for me since I don't have any help.

I'm going to need roughly 10 cubic yards of concrete. When I worked in the UK, they used silos. But it was meant for commercial projects only so I'm not sure if they have something for residentials too now here in Ohio, USA.

Small cement silo 5 cubic yards left in my backyard for a day would be great. This way I could do it at my own pace.

[image]

Comment: Why is 2 hours not enough - will you have to wheelbarrow loads of concrete from the truck to your sports court because the truck can't get close enough to unload directly where you need it? Would a concrete pump help you get the stuff where it needs to go in a reasonable time?

Comment: @brhans, do you think I could spread 760 sq.ft of concrete in 2 hours just by myself?

Comment: Well - pouring concrete in batches is usually asking for trouble. You'd want to get the whole area very roughly covered in those 2 hours, and then finish it nicely afterwards. Possibly you could have the concrete company put a retarder in the mix to give you more time to work it.

Comment: @Grasper Find a bunch of strong young lads (above the legal drinking age), that are willing to work for beer.  Have them wheel the concrete from the truck to the site, while you spread and tool the concrete.  Then give them the beer, and send them on their way.  Note: Don't give them the beer until they're done, no matter how thirsty they claim to be. Or ask the delivery company if they have a [concrete pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_pump) that can reach the site.

Comment: Google: ***mix onsite** concrete near me*. But keep in mind you have to *pay* for a minimum (7 yards in my area IIRC) and extra if the truck's there for over ~2 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time from when the cement, water, sand and particulate are mixed till the time the mix should be in your forms is limited. That is a primary reason that a delivery truck can only stay at your lot for a max time (they have a secondary consideration of keeping the truck on the road delivering other jobs but many companies may stay longer for an overtime charge).

Since you need a lot more time and 10 yards is an awful large amount of material for one person to handle all at once you are left with two choices.
1. Order raw materials and rent a mixer and perform small batch mixes on site.
2. Prepare all your forms and rebar ahead of time and then prepare to have a crew available to get the job laid down in the time that a truck can be there.

Note that if you are doing something in small batch mixing this is not the best approach when there is slab work and continuous foundation that you would like to all bond together. There is also the issue of getting a slab surface finished right when it is poured over too long of time in small pieces.

Comment: ok, so if I prepare everything and get a crew to lay it down. How much do you think the cost will be to pay them? I'm trying to save as much as possible that's why I wanted to do it myself. Here I see https://www.fixr.com/costs/concrete-driveway-paving#cQ the cost if they set up all.

Comment: Obviously this differs based on location, etc (and is off-topic here) but I was quoted about $3,000 to break up and remove all the concrete in my garage, bring in road base to fix the slope, and replace it with a new slab. It's about 30'x25'. Not sure how much of that was the removal and how much was the new pour.